# Does human psychology has a theory about most people only sees what they want to see?

Tags: social-psychology

The movie [The Sixth Sense](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167404/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) had perhaps one big theme: [dead people only see what they want to see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPSQswV2fLc).

But it does seem that can be more general: do living people actually do that too? This led to the question: does human psychology has a theory about most people only see what they want to see?

And as a result, one way to have really good personal relationship is to show them what they want to see, or say what they want to hear?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This looks like a duplicate of a common question on this forum - see https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13701/7001 and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13173/7001 for several examples - the answer is "confirmation bias".  Do you agree that your question is answered elsewhere?